# Can you log PIC time with an instructor without being currently enrolled in a flight school?

Tags: student-pilot, pic

Been doing discovery flights with a friend who is a CFI. Am I legally allowed to log PIC time without being enrolled at a flight school? Want to know before logging /flying.

Comment: PS enrolling in a flight school in May just getting some experience.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S. you can log PIC time if you have a Student Pilot Certificate and a medical certificate, and your instructor has made all of the appropriate endorsements allowing you to "solo."

Being enrolled in a "Flight School" is not a requirement for solo/PIC flight. But you  must be undergoing training for a pilot certificate or rating.  See (4) (iii) below:

Here is the relevant U.S. Federal Aviation Regulation (FAR): [**14 CFR 61.51(e)(4)**](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.51(e)(4))

> (4) A student pilot may log pilot-in-command time only when the student pilot -
>
> > (i) Is the **sole occupant of the aircraft** or is performing the duties of pilot of command of an airship requiring more than one pilot flight crewmember;

> > (ii) Has a solo flight endorsement as required under § 61.87 of this part; and

> > (iii) Is undergoing training for a pilot certificate or rating.

*(emphasis is mine)*

If your CFI friend is giving you flight instruction during these "discovery flights" the time can be logged as flight training (i.e., dual instruction/flight training received) before you obtain a Student Pilot Certificate or medical certificate. See these two references: [reference 1](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/become/student_cert) and [reference 2](https://www.faa.gov/faq?combine=&field_faq_category_target_id=11581)